# Поиск информации по сайту средствами Python и сопоставление с введёнными данными

Tags: python

Если говорить подробно:у меня есть сайт в интернете в котором столбцом 100к+ слов и ничего больше. Мне нужно так, чтобы когда пользователь вводит любое слово проходила проверка условия что это слово было на том сайте  и следовательно выводило true или false. Есть ли возможность реализовать такую вещь?

А если нет, то можно ли как нибудь рационально создать огромный список/кортеж из этих слов к которому можно обращаться по тем же запросам?

если ещё подробнее: пишу мини-игру в которой тебе даётся комбинация 3 букв и пользователь должен ввести существующее слово (на английском языке) в котором есть эта комбинация

Answer (score 0):

Столбец на 100k+ это очень не рационально, не знаю сколько грузится страница но полагаю не быстро, для оптимизации можно использовать некоторые алгоритмы, если нужна проверка на наличие слова то можно использовать например древовидную структуру где каждая буква представляется родительским элементом для следующей.

к примеру у нас есть слова (для простоты я взял одну общую букву в начале)

"лес", "лесоруб", "леска", "лось"

Далее мы готовим словарное дерево. По сути оно готовится 1 раз при условии что слова никогда не будут добавляться, далее его можно загружать из `json` файла.

*Словарное дерево будет компактнее изначального словаря, так как многие слова (совпадающие началом) будут накладываться друг на друга — так мы экономим память.*

*Чтобы сэкономить скорость мы обращаемся по хэшу (буквы в данном случае) к структуре что по сути является гораздо более быстрой операцией условно можно считать это `O(n)` где `n` — длина слова а не словаря*

Примерный алгоритм обработки представлен ниже, не хочу лишать Вас возможности доработать его на свой вкус.

Важный момент: символ `.` нужен для того чтобы убедится что мы нашли слово целиком.

```js
const dict = ["лес", "лесоруб", "леска", "лось"]
const tree = {}

for (const word of dict){
  let index = 0
  let root = null
  for(const letter of word){
    if (index === 0){
      root = tree[letter] ? tree[letter] : tree[letter] = {}
    } else {
      root = root[letter] ? root[letter] : root[letter] = {} 
    }
    index += 1
  }
  root['.'] = '.'
}

console.log('словарное дерево', tree)

//проверка слов

function wordExist(word){
  let root = tree;
  for (const letter of word + '.'){
    if (root[letter]){
      root = root[letter]
    } else {
      return `слова "${word}" нет`
    }
  }
  return `слово "${word}" найдено`
}
console.log(wordExist('лесоруб'))
console.log(wordExist('лесорубка'))
```

Теперь после того как я продемонстировал работу алгоритма приведу его на языке `python`:

```
dictionary = ["лес", "лесоруб", "леска", "лось"]
tree = {}

for word in dictionary: 
  index = 0
  root = None
  for letter in word:
    if (index == 0):
      if (letter in tree): 
        root = tree[letter] 
      else: 
        root = tree[letter] = {}
    else:
      if (letter in root):
        root = root[letter]
      else:
        root[letter] = {}
    index += 1
  root['.'] = '.'

def wordExist(word):
  root = tree;
  for letter in word + '.':
    if letter in root:
      root = root[letter]
    else:
      return f'слова "{word}" нет'
  return f'слово "{word}" найдено'

print(wordExist('лесоруб'))
print(wordExist('лесорубка'))
```

Answer (score 0):

> тебе даётся комбинация 3 букв и пользователь должен ввести
> существующее слово (на английском языке) в котором есть эта комбинация

А зачем этот файл на сервере?! Берём введённое слово и проверяем наличие заданной комбинации букв одним вызовом:

```
cod = 'abl'

resp = input(f"Введите слово, содержащее '{cod}' : ")
if resp.find(cod) > 0:
    print('Правильно!')
else:
    print('Вы ошиблись :-(')
```

Если же вам надо проверить, что введённая строка является настоящим словом английского языка, то проще всего использовать API любого сервиса переводчика, типа https://translate.google.ru/. Наверняка, там есть код возврата, который соответствует тому, что искомого слова нет в словаре.

И это будет гораздо надёжнее, чем использовать какие-то 100-тысячные списки, составленные неизвестно кем и неизвестно как. :-)